# Exception when using Pheanstalk lib to put new data on Beanstalkd

Tags: php, beanstalkd, pheanstalk

I'm using Pheanstalk library to work with Beanstalkd

I'm using this code to put new data on a tube:

```
$pheanstalk = Pheanstalk\Pheanstalk::create($ip);
$pheanstalk->useTube($tubename)->put($data, Pheanstalk::DEFAULT_PRIORITY, $delay);
```

The `$tubename` variable is `string`.But I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Pheanstalk\Pheanstalk::useTube(): Argument #1
> ($tube) must be of type Pheanstalk\Values\TubeName, string given

The name of the tube obviously will be `string` !, how should I pass tube's name?

The example mentioned [here](https://github.com/pheanstalk/pheanstalk) is also using string value for Tube's name

Comment: Read word for word. A string not expected, but a TubeName instance.

Comment: @MarkusZeller Yes, but the official example is using string directly, anyway, it resolved, thanks

Comment: Good news: my PR was already accepted, so the documentation is on point, now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Pheanstalk::useTube()`](https://github.com/pheanstalk/pheanstalk/blob/f1a435587a4f6f916d793b795e79d6eab30cea37/src/Pheanstalk.php#L140) method signature changed in version 5:

```
public function useTube(TubeName $tube): void
```

So now you should pass the tube name like this:

```
$pheanstalk->useTube(new \Pheanstalk\Values\TubeName($tubename));
```